# Duplicating a table with partitions in SQL

Tags: hive

the current database at my work runs on SQL script to generate data as outputs to use, one of the data I often use might be updated so I'm trying to create a back up copy or a duplicate, unfortunately,  I'm a novice in SQL. The system is called Waterdrop and it's not widely used but it runs on Hive SQL.

My understanding of SQL is that this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE acc_backup LIKE acct;    
INSERT INTO acc_backup SELECT * FROM acct;
```

However, I get an error

> Need to specify partition columns because the destination table is partitioned

Not realizing this table had partitions, I then checked:

```
SHOW PARTITIONS acct;
```

And in the column dat_dt (which is date not string or decimal) there are 198 partitions that looks like

```
dat_dt= 2017-09-25
dat_dt= 2017-09-30
dat_dt= 2017-10-05
dat_dt= 2017-10-08
... 198 rows
```

So how would I copy the data from acc to acc_backup? The table is very big so it takes a long time to run these codes, should I try

```
CREATE TABLE acc_backup AS SELECT * FROM acct;
```

or perhaps ：

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS acc_backup 
SELECT * INTO acc_backup FROM acct;
```

Or would I need to create an empty table with the exact same 198 partitions to copy the data and how would I attempt that? My ultimate goal is to keep this original chart the same and a backup, so structure/partition of the new table isn't my main concern as long as the data is the same!

Thank you very much! Any notes or suggestion is appreciated. And again sorry I tagged SQL Server before as you can tell I'm very novice to the SQL databases, thanks everyone for correcting me!

Comment: `CREATE TABLE acc_backup LIKE acct;` isn't valid syntax for [tag:sql-server]. Are you sure you've tagged your question correctly for your database system?

Comment: "CREATE TABLE acc_backup AS SELECT * FROM acct;" this statement wont create table in sql server. are you tahhed corrrect database system?

Comment: @MIchael . . . Your code would not run in SQL Server.  You need to tag with the database you are really using if you want an answer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right, I removed the tag! Sorry about the inconvenience!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are right, the product we use is called Waterdrop which I guess is not a popular enough product to have a tag, but Ill read through the post you tagged and see where I should post this, thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes , you can use the direct data transfer using select * into newtable... The newtable will be created in the same schema. Thanks

Comment: @user3315556 great I'll try that and let it run and see if it works, appreciate it!